Postman Request
How to send different kind of request in postman(Post, Get, Put, Patch, Delete, Head, Option)
Details explanation about How to send different kind of request in postman(Post, Get, Put, Patch, Delete, Head, Option) in node.js for backend

Please see the Send your first API request documentation.
